# Show that $d'(x,y)=\min\{1,d(x,y)\}$ induces the same topology as $d$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

**Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space and define: $d' : M$x$M \rightarrow R$**

---

**Show that $d'(x,y)=\min\{1,d(x,y)\}$ induces the same topology as $d$**

---

I know that $d'$ defines a metric on M, since d is a matric (satisfying positivity, symmetry and triangle inequality. But how do I show it induces the same topology?

Comment: What is the characterisation of $d$-open sets, and what is the characterisation of $d'$-open sets? Can you see that they are the same?

Comment: @DanielFischer $d$-open sets at p are of the form  $U_{\epsilon}$={ $x \in X | d(x,p)< \epsilon$}. $d'$-open sets at p are of the form  $U_{\epsilon}$={ $x \in X |$ min{1, $d(x,p)< \epsilon$}}.......So these correspond as long as $\epsilon < 1$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:**  Show that:

1. For any *ball* defined with the $d$ metric, you can find a ball defined with the $d'$ metric contained in the $d$-ball.
2. For any $d'$-ball, show you can find a $d$-ball contained in it.  You only need to work with balls since they form a basis for the metric topology.

I'll help you do the second part, and I'll leave the first part to you.  Suppose we have $B_{d'}(x,r)$.  I claim $B_{d}(x,r) \subseteq B_{d'}(x,r)$.  Why?  Let $y \in B_{d}(x,r)$.  Then $d(x,y) < r$.  But since $d'$ is the minimum of $d$ and $1$, then $d' \leq d$.  So we have $d'(x,y) \leq d(x,y) < r$, which implies $d'(x,y) < r$, so $y \in B_{d'}(x,r)$.  That shows us $B_{d}(x,r) \subseteq B_{d'}(x,r)$.

**By the way**: The purpose of this assignment, and the take home lesson you should take from it once you're done proving it, is that in the metric topology, only the small open balls matter.  We can discard all larger open balls.  So if you threw away all open balls of radius $3$ or larger, you would still have the same topology.  If you threw away all balls of radius $.0000002$ or larger, you'd still have the same topology. Only the small balls matter.

Comment: For two metrics $ d$ and $e$  on a set $ S$, let their topologies be $ T_d$ and $T_e$.  Let $e<^*d$ mean that $ \exists k>0\;\forall x,y\in S  \; (e(x,y)\leq  k d(x,y)).$  Then $ e<^*d \implies T_e\subset T_d.$ If you know this, then in your Q you only need to show $T_d\subset T_{d'}$

Comment: @user46944 Throwing away a ball of radius 0.0000002, wouldn't it create a problem ?

Comment: @Siddharth Well, if you agree with the problem statement, then no it wouldn't.  Let $d'$ be the metric such that all points are at most $.000000000000002$.  In other words, $d'(x,y) := \min\{.000000000000002, d(x,y)  \}$.  Then there aren't any balls of radius exactly $.0000002$, yet by the problem statement, $d'$ induces the same topology as $d$.

Comment: @Siddharth When I say "throw away balls of radius $.0000002$" I mean removing distances of $.0000002$ from the metric.  That's what $d'$ does.  It makes distances between points at most $.000000000000002$.  Yet it induces the same metric as $d$.  So I don't mean physically "remove" all of the balls of $.0000002$ from the topology.  I misspoke by saying "throw away".  Sorry about that.

Comment: @user46944 d'(x,y):= min(a, d(x, y)) where a > 0, then the metric induced by d'(x, y) is same as of d(x, y). Is this correct ?

Comment: @Siddharth No, they aren't the same metric. Take $a = 1$.  Consider $x=1$ and $y=5$.  $d(x,y) = 4$ while $d'(x,y) = 1$.  For them to be the same, they have to assign the same distance to each pair of points.  On the other hand, even though they aren't the same metric, they *do* generate the same topology!  The $d'$ metric basically says, for example, and ball of radius $1$ or greater under the $d$ metric becomes the entire space under the $d'$ metric.  So in a sense we really are "throwing away" balls of $d$-radius $2$, for example, since under the $d'$ metric, the ball of radius $2$ becomes

Comment: @Siddharth ...the entire space.  The fact that $d$ and $d'$ are different metrics ($d'$ can be thought of as the metric that restricts open balls to be of radius less than $1$, and any $d$-ball of radius $\geq 1$ just becomes the entire space under $d'$) - this fact that $d$ and $d'$ are different yet induce the same topology illustrates that only the "small" balls matter in a metric induced topology.  We can discard of larger sets and still all of the continuous functions with respect to $d$ are continuous with respect to $d'$, and all sequences converging in $d$ converge in $d'$, etc.

Comment: @Siddharth Only the small open sets matter.

Comment: @user46944 Actually my bad,  d and d' are not same but topology induced by them is same. btw thanks for explaining everything.

Comment: @Siddharth You're welcome!

Comment: @user46944 I am trying to show Part 1. of your hint myself, and I am having a lot of trouble. I started out with "Suppose $B_{d}(x,r)$ is an open ball in the $d$ metric. We claim that $B_{d^{\prime}}(x,r) \subseteq B_{d}(x,r)$, where $B_{d^{\prime}}$ is an open ball in the $d^{\prime}$ metric. Let $y \in B_{d^{\prime}}(x,r)$. Then, $d^{\prime}(x,y)<r$. Since $d^{\prime}(x,y) = \min (d(x,y), 1) < r$, if $d^{\prime}(x,y) = d(x,y)$, then $d^{\prime}(x,y) = d(x,y) < r$ and of course $B_{d^{\prime}}(x,r) \subseteq B_{d}(x,r)$". It's the case where $d^{\prime}(x,y) = 1$ that I'm having trouble with.

Comment: @user46944 If $d^{\prime}(x,y) = 1$, then, by definition of $d^{\prime}$, $1 < d(x,y)$. So, then is $1 = r$, then? Somehow I need to get $d(x,y) < d^{\prime}(x,y)$ in order to get that $B_{d^{\prime}}(x,r) \subseteq B_{d}(x,r)$ and I really don't see how that is going to happen. Can you please help me?

Comment: @JessyunBourne The idea you should have in your head is that since $d'$ is $\min\{d, 1\}$, if you are choosing your radius $r$ as $r < 1$, then $d' < r$ implies $d < r$ since when $d' < r$, $d' = d$, right?  So that means $d'$-balls of radius $< 1$ are exactly the same as $d$-balls of radius $<1$.  The only trouble is if you are looking at balls of radius $r \geq 1$.  A $d'$-ball of radius $r \geq 1$ is actually the whole space!  While a $d$-ball of radius $r \geq 1$ is definitely not the whole space.  So that already shows you in general $B_{d'}(x,r) \not \subseteq B_{d}(x,r)$ for $r \geq 1$.

Comment: @JessyunBourne So that already shows you your argument is a little flawed in the case of $r \geq 1$.  But the object of the game isn't to show $B_{d'}(x,r) \subseteq B_{d}(x,r)$.  It's to show you can find a $d'$-ball of *some* radius contained in $B_{d}(x,r)$.  So you need to find some $\tilde{r}>0$ so that $B_{d'}(x,\tilde{r}) \subseteq B_{d}(x, r)$.  **Hint**:  Check out the first comment under my answer.  It basically say if metric $d'$ satisfies $d'(x,y) \leq kd(x,y)$ for some real $k > 0$, then we can find $\tilde{r}$ such that $B_{d'}(x,\tilde{r}) \subseteq B_{d}(x, r)$.

Comment: @JessyunBourne Clearly, for $k = 1$, and $d' := \min\{d,1\}$, we have $d'(x,y) \leq kd(x,y)$.  So your job now is, given an arbitrary $r > 0$ and considering $B_{d}(x,r)$, to search for a radius $\tilde{r}$ so that $B_{d'}(x,\tilde{r}) \subseteq B_{d}(x,r)$.  If you can't figure it out, let me know, but think about it for a few minutes first.  Good luck!

Comment: @JessyunBourne Have you gotten it yet?  I'll tell you what I think the proof should be, and you let me know if you got anything different or if you don't agree with what I've done.  So, we know if $r < 1$, then $B_{d'}(x,r) = B_{d}(x,r)$, right?  Well, let's take $\tilde{r} := \min\{r, \frac{1}{2}\}$.  (You can choose any number less than one and replace $\frac{1}{2}$ with it, and the proof will be the same.)  Then $\tilde{r} < 1$, and so $B_{d'}(x,\tilde{r}) = B_{d}(x,\tilde{r})$.  But since $\tilde{r} \leq r$, we know $B_{d}(x,\tilde{r}) \subseteq B_{d}(x,r)$, implying...

Comment: @JessyunBourne ...that $B_{d'}(x, \tilde{r}) \subseteq B_{d}(x,r)$.  So, we've shown 1 in the original answer, namely that for any $d$-ball, we can find a $d'$-ball contained in the $d$-ball.  (Of course, the $d'$-ball has radius different than the $d$-ball, even though in 2 of the original answer, we were able to use the same radius for the $d$-ball and the $d'$-ball.)

Comment: @layman's sir, can't we prove (1) using same radius for both the balls? If not then " how can be (1) true for above matrices"?

Answer (score 1):

Since we are in metric spaces, we have nice definition of closed sets, that a limit point is contained in it, so we can try approaching this problem with that fact too. Showing that they induce the same topology is equivalent to showing that any closed set in one metric is closed in the other one also (because complement of open sets is closed)

Let $A$ be a closed set in $(X,d)$ and $x_n$ be any converging sequence in $A$ such that $(x_n) \to x \in A$. Therefore, eventually $d(x_n,x)<\epsilon<1 \implies d'(x_n, x) \leq d(x_n,x)<\epsilon<1$. Hence, $(x_n) \to x \in A$ in the metric $(X,d')$.

For the other way round, let $A$ be a closed set in $(X,d')$ and $x_n$ be any converging sequence in $A$ such that $(x_n) \to x \in A$. Therefore, eventually $d'(x_n,x)<\epsilon<1$. Since, $d'(x,y) < 1 \implies d(x,y) = d'(x,y) \forall x, y\in X$, we have that $d(x_n, x) = d'(x_n,x)<\epsilon<1$ eventually. Hence, $(x_n) \to x \in A$ in the metric $(X,d)$.