# A confusion about the case: the metric $\bar d ( x , y ) = \min \{ d ( x , y ) , 1 \}$ defines the same topology as $d$

Tags: general-topology

In the book of *Topology* by Munkres, at page 121-122, it is given that

> Let X be a metric space with metric $d$. Define $\bar d:X\times X \to
>  R$ by the equation $$\bar d ( x , y ) = \min \{ d ( x , y ) , 1 \}$$ .
>   Then $\bar d$ is a metric that induces the same topology as d.
>
> [...]
>
> Now we note that in any metric space, the collection of
>   $\epsilon-balls$ with $\epsilon < 1$ forms a basis for the metric
>   topology , for every basis element containing $x$ contains such an
>   $\epsilon-ball$ centered at $x$.

I can easily prove that $\bar d$ indeed defines the same topology as $d$, as it is shown in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1614459/show-that-dx-y-min-1-dx-y-induces-the-same-topology-as-d) question, but my actual question is the following:

If two topologies are the same, they have to have the same open set; however, consider the ball $B(x, 2)$.By definition

$$B(x, 2) = \{ y | d(x,y) < 2\}$$.

Now consider this set in the topology generated by $\bar d$. This set is not open in the topology induced by $\bar d$ because $\bar d$ the distance of any element to $x$ is at most $1$, so the ones whose distance to x was $1.5$ and $3$ are now in the distance $1$ to $x$, so clearly $B(x, 2)$ is not open in the topology induced by $\bar d$, so how can two topologies be the same when they do not contain the same open sets ?

**Edit:**

My main objection is that there is not set in the topology induced by $\bar d$ that contains the same elements as $B(x,2)$ in the topology induced by $d$, so how can this two topologies be the same since one does not contain an open set that the other has ?

Comment: I don't follow your argument; If I understand correctly you say that $B(x,2)$ is not open with $\tilde{d}$ because you cannot find a ball centered at $x$  using $\tilde{d}$ that covers $B(2,x)$. But for a set to be open you just need for every point $x\in B(2,x)$ to find a ball $B$ such that $B$ is contained in $B(2,x)$.

Comment: @onurcanbektas your objection is wrong. It is open in both topologies.

Comment: @CalvinKhor There is not set that containing the same elements as $B(x,2)$ in the topology induced by $d$ in the topology induced by $\bar d$, so how can a set that do not exist in the topology be open ?

Comment: Are you aware that e.g. the union of two balls is open?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Can you express $B(x,2)$ as union of open ball in the metric $\bar d$ ?

Comment: @clark see my edit please.

Comment: @onurcanbektas yes.

Comment: @onurcanbektas edited my answer to include this union.

Comment: $A=B(x,2)$ is a subset of $X$. And you want to show that $A$ belongs in the topology induced by $\tilde{d}$. I think there is a confusion because $A$ in defined in terms of $d$, but you should view $A$ as just a set you want to prove it is open. In order to show that $A$ is an element of the topology induced by $\tilde{d}$ you have to show that for every $x\in A$ there is an open set $V$ such that $V \subset A$. Below there are answers that do exactly that.

Comment: @clark Yes, that is why I have accepted that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asserting that $B_d(x,2) = \{ y; d(x,y) < 2\}$ is not of the form $B_{\bar d}(x,r) = \{ y; \bar d(x,y) < r\}$, and this is true. But this doesnt invalidate openness; there are other open sets than balls.

Notice that for each $y\in B_d(x,2)$, then for $r=  \min(1/2,2-d(x,y)) > 0 $, we have that $$\bar d(y,y')<r ⟹  d(y',x) ≤  d(y,y') + d(y,x) < 2- d(x,y) +  d(x,y) = 2$$
Thus $B_{\bar d}(y,r) \subset B_d(x,2)$. For each such $y$ we have one $r=r(y)$. Now notice that
$$B_d(x,2) = \bigcup_{y\in {B_d(x,2)} } B_{\bar d} (y,r(y))$$

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the open sets coincide does not mean that the open balls are identical.

Comment: Then what does "the open sets coincide" exactly mean ?

Comment: The open balls form a base for the topology. All open sets can be written as (arbitrary) unions of open balls. For instance, the Euclidean balls for a basis of the topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$, but so do the boxes from the max-norm. The open balls are very different, but every open set can be written as a union of either open Euclidean ball or open boxes.

Comment: @onurcanbektas "open sets coincide" means "give the same topology". Two metrics can give the same topology without having the same open balls.

Comment: @Arthur But we are allowed to show that two topologies are the same by showing that one is a subset of another and vice versa. If what you are saying is true, we could not do that.

Comment: I mean set theoretically, for example, we need to have $\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2$ and $\tau_2 \subseteq \tau_1$, hence one open set needs to be in the other topology as well.

Comment: @onurcanbectas But open balls are not the only open sets. You also have _arbitrary unions_ of open balls.

Comment: @Arthur Can you express $B(x,2)$ as unions of open balls in the topology induced by $\bar d$.

Comment: @onurcanbektas Sure. Let $\bar B$ mean open ball in $\bar d$ (and not closed ball). Then we have $$B(x,2)=\bigcup_{y\in B(x,2)}\bar B(y, \min\{0.5, 2-d(x,y)\})$$which is the union of an open $\bar d$-ball around every single element in $B(x,2)$ (so the union contains $B(x,2)$) with a radius such that by the triangle inequality every single one of them is contained in $B(x,2)$ (so $B(x,2)$ contains the union). There is probably a lot of overlap, and many of the balls may be unnecessary, but that doesn't matter. The min is just there to make sure we never have a radius $\geq1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Arthur, even though I have still some problems about show that $B(x,2)$ contains the union, I mostly got it.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone already said, in order to compare two topologies, you don't need to show that their balls are the same, but their *open sets*. If both topologies are induced by metrics, the relevant property for you is the following: you need to prove that for every point $x$ in every $\overline{d}$-ball $x\in \overline{B}$ there is a $d$-ball $B$ such that $x \in B \subset \overline{B}$. And vice-versa. And of course you can do that for your metrics, can't you?

Comment: Nope. Suppose $X=\mathbb R$ with natural topology $d(x,y)=|x-y|$. Then $B(0,2)$ in $\overline d$ is the whole set $\mathbb R$, which is not a ball wrt. $d$ (there's no ball with infinite radius). Of course, $X$ itself is an open set in a topological space $X$, but it's not necessarily a ball.

Comment: @CiaPan And this contradicts what I was saying, how? Again: you *don't* need to prove that the balls are the same.

Comment: Another way of saying this is for every $\tilde{d}$ ball $\tilde{B}$ there is a $d$ ball $B$ such that $B\subset \tilde{B}$ and vice versa.

Comment: Ahhh, I have read your answer in wrong direction! I understood you mean 'for each $\overline B$ there exists $B$ _enclosing_ $\overline B$', instead of _contained in_ $\overline B$.

Answer (score 0):

When something is wrong in a mathematical reasoning, it's most often at the words like *obviously*, *clearly* etc.

In your case:

> because $\overline d$ the distance of any element to $x$ is at most $1$, so the ones whose distance to $x$ was $1.5$ and $3$ are now in the distance $1$ to $x$, so *clearly* $B(x,2)$ is not open in the topology induced by $\overline d$

As you correctly note *each* $y$ in your space is not farther than $1$ from any chosen $x$ wrt. $\overline d$, so a ball with radius $2$ is the whole space, and as such it *is* open.

Comment: After reading that sentence 5 min ago, I have confused myself on which point that I was confused. Therefore, I advice you to read my edit.