# How to prove that two topology are the same?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have two topology for $\mathbb{R}$, the given by the usual metric ($d_{1}(x,y)=|x-y|$) and that second one given by the metric $$d_{2}(x,y)=\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$$ i can't think how to prove that two topology are the same. There a any theorem or conditions that can assure that for any two metric or any algorithm for this case?

Comment: The most straightforward approach is to show that every $d_1$-open ball around $x$ contains a $d_2$-open ball around $x$, and vice-versa. A nice way to present it is to prove that the identity map $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is continuous with respect to $d_1$ and $d_2$, and also with respect to $d_2$ and $d_1$. Alternatively, you could argue that $d_1$ is [equivalent to](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1614459/473276) $\min\{1, d_1\}$ is Lipschitz equivalent to $d_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key point here is that $d_2(x, y) = f(d_1(x, y))$, where $f$ is the continuous strictly increasing function
$$
f(x)
= \frac{x}{1 + x} = \frac{1}{1 + x^{-1}},
$$
which satisfies $f(0) = 0$.

Now, the bases for the two topologies are the collections of open balls
$$
\mathcal{B}_1
= \{B_1(x; \epsilon) : x \in \mathbf{R}, \epsilon > 0\},
\qquad
\mathcal{B}_2
= \{B_2(x; \epsilon) : x \in \mathbf{R}, \epsilon \in (0, 1)\},
$$
(where $B_k(x, \epsilon) = \{y \in \mathbf{R} : d_k(x, y) < \epsilon\}$).
We show that the two topologies are equivalent by showing that these bases are equal.

Since $f$ is continuous and increasing, it is also invertible as a function $f\colon [0, \infty) \rightarrow [0, 1)$, and we have that, for any $B_2(x; \epsilon) \in \mathcal{B}_2$ that
$$
B_2(x, \epsilon)
= \{y \in \mathbf{R} : f(d_1(x, y)) < \epsilon\}
= \{y \in \mathbf{R} : d_1(x, y) < f^{-1}(\epsilon)\}
= B_1(x_0; f^{-1}(\epsilon)) \in \mathcal{B}_1.
$$

Similarly, for any $B_1(x, \epsilon) \in \mathcal{B}_1$,
$$
B_1(x, \epsilon)
= \{y \in \mathbf{R} : d_1(x, y) < \epsilon\}
= \{y \in \mathbf{R} : f(d_1(x, y)) < f(\epsilon)\}
= B_2(x_0; f(\epsilon)) \in \mathcal{B}_2.
$$

Thus, $\mathcal{B}_1 = \mathcal{B}_2$, and so the corresponding topologies are the same.